# firemonkey indy udp Synchronize Thread

Tags: multithreading, udp, firemonkey, indy, synchronize

Good day.
I create a class instance Thread.
In this thread I create udpserver.
UDPREAD synchronizes with the main thread.

Question: How to synchronize not with the main thread but with the thread that is the parent of the UDP

thank you

Answer (score 1):

`TIdUDPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  Internally, it runs a separate reading thread for each item that you setup in the `TIdUDPServer.Bindings` collection.  When a given `Binding` receives incoming data, the corresponding thread reads the data and then fires the `OnUDPRead` event.

By default, the `OnUDPRead` event handler is called in the context of the main UI thread, via a call to `TThread.Synchronize()`.  If you want to avoid that, you need to set the `TIdUDPServer.ThreadedEvent` property to true.  The event handler will then be called in the context of the `Binding`'s reading thread directly, and you can synchronize your event handler's code with your server's parent thread however you want.

Comment: it means you can synchronize not only with the main stream, but also with the stream by the parent UDP, TThread.Synchronize(nil, MyThreadProcedure)

Comment: It means you can synchronize (pieces of) your event handler code however you want.